# Unable to set JApplet Background Color

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, japplet

My problem is that when trying to set the background color in a JApplet i'm trying to create, i am unable to get any color other than the default gray.

I would really appreciate it if someone was able to not only tell me whats wrong but also explain it. This technique was learned through a textbook and so, i want to understand the problem so that i know what is going on.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

SDG

```
public class QuoteApplet extends JApplet
{

    public void paint (Graphics appPage)
    {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        appPage.drawRect(65,55,255,100);
        //page.drawRect(60,80,225,30);
        //page.drawOval(75,65, 20, 20);
        appPage.drawLine(30,30,30,100);
        appPage.drawLine(40,30,40,100);
        appPage.drawLine(55,45,15,85);

        appPage.drawString("There once lived a man named Oedipus Rex.", 70, 70);
        appPage.drawString("You may have heard about his odd complex.", 70, 90);
        appPage.drawString("His name appears in Freud's index,", 70, 110);
        appPage.drawString("'cause he loved his mother.", 70, 130);
        appPage.drawString("-Tom Lehrer", 200, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the interesting poem. Also, good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to set the background color of the applet's contentPane, not the applet itself. So call `getContentPane().setBackground(...)`. And you ***don't*** want to do this from within the paint method. Instead do it in `init()`. In fact, it is rare that you'll ever want to override a JApplet's paint method, and certainly not here. You're much better drawing in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel or other class that derives from JComponent and then adding that to the contentPane, or using it as the contentPane.

Comment: if i create an init() method, do i then need to change anything in my paint method or is it just as simple as adding another method?

Comment: @superdem: You would add the init() as a separate method. But see my edit above -- you should not be overriding `paint(...)` to begin with.

Comment: thank you, if what you said is true (and i don't doubt it for a second), my textbook is the stupidest thing on the planet...

They legitimately set it up the same way i did. I have copied their code word for word and only changed the values...

Comment: @superdemongob: what book do you use (so I can avoid it)?

Comment: Java Software Solutions: Foundations of Program Design - Lewis and Loftus.       This specific travesty occurs on page 102.

Comment: try core java vol I and vol II or deitel and deitel java how to program
both r nice books

Comment: @lucifer: yep I've got them and also recommend them.

Comment: I was going to buy the McGrawHill Java: A Complete Reference. Any idea on how that is?

Comment: @superdemon: I don't know as I've never used that book.